# delay execution of code with QTimer and Eventloop

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, signals, qtimer

I want my program to wait for the timeout of the QTimer to execute a specific method. The function does some calculation in a loop and after that loop finishes it should wait for the timer to timeout and run again after the timer event finished.

Here is the current state of the code that generates the thread and connects the timer to the generateData() method. This code is executed in the constructor of Class.

```
timer = new QTimer(0);
timer->setTimerType(Qt::PreciseTimer);
timer->setInterval(40); //25 frames per second


QThread *thread = new QThread(this);
moveToThread(thread);
timer->moveToThread(thread);

connect(thread, SIGNAL(started()), timer, SLOT(start()));
connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(timerEvent()));
connect(thread, SIGNAL(started()), this, SLOT(generateData()));
connect(this, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(quit()));

thread->start();
```

method, which should wait for timer after execution of for loop

```
void Class::generateData() {
    while (1) {
        calculation()
        //do some calculation, which takes around 3-5ms
        QEventLoop loop;
        connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
        loop.exec();
    }
}
```

The eventloop does not seem to stop the method from being executed in that time.
Is there some other way to do this?

Comment: provide a [mcve], what are `object1` and `object1->at(i)->test();`?

Comment: Aren't you actually just looking for [QThread::msleep](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#msleep)?

Comment: I updated the question, but the calculation loop doesn't really matter to the question

Comment: Never do that. You're reentering the event loop. Simply don't. You don't have to.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach looks unnecessary complicated. I would do the following:

```
void Class::generateData()
{
    // Do calculations.
    for (int i = 0; i<object1->size(); ++i)
    {
      object1->at(i)->test();
    }
    // Wait a little bit and do calculations again.
    QTimer::singleShot(40, this, SLOT(generateData()));
}
```

Note, that I got rid of `while` loop, because timer recursively calls the same function.

Comment: The problem with this approach is, that I lose the  precision of the timing, since I wait for the calculation to finish and then start the timer. But I'd like to do the calculations while the timer is running, so the event is at least nearly accurately called every 40ms .

Comment: in that case you should just connect the generateData() to the timer.timeout() slot and possibly call moveToThread for you `Class`. Qt handles the thread boundaries for you

Comment: Doesnt't that have same problem, since the calculation is started, when the timer  is timed out? Since the calculation is taking up to 5ms I won't be that accurate

Comment: @todayihateprogramming, you might measure the calculation time and adjust timeout to make it always be 40ms. If, say, calculation takes 5ms, you will set `QTimer::singleShot(40 - 5, this, SLOT(generateData()));`, so that the overall time will still be 40ms.

Comment: As I also added to my answer, I think this is not the case, since the timer is actually using a system call, which will trigger independently from the thread usage

Comment: The calculation depends on a ton of variables and is not constant.  I hoped there would be a way to just wait after the calculation is finished, but while (timer.isactive()); doesn't seem to work

Comment: I have also seen implementations that use a QElapsedTimer started at the beginning of the calculation and then measured at the end, that elapsed time is then subtracted from 40ms and the result is used in QThread::usleep or QThread::msleep

Comment: That might be worth a try. Good idea!

Answer (score 0):

Combining the hints you gave on other answers, I think this is what you are looking for:

```
Class::Class(QObject *parent)
{
    timer = new QTimer(0);
    timer->setTimerType(Qt::PreciseTimer);
    timer->setInterval(40); //25 frames per second

    QThread *thread = new QThread(this);
    moveToThread(thread);
    timer->moveToThread(thread);
    this->moveToThread(thread);

    connect(thread, SIGNAL(started()), timer, SLOT(start()));
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(generateData()));
    connect(this, SIGNAL(finished()), timer, SLOT(stop()));
    connect(this, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(quit()));

    thread->start();
}

void Class::generateData()
{
    // Do calculations.
    for (int i = 0; i<object1->size(); ++i)
    {
        object1->at(i)->test();
    }
}
```

Every time the timer times out it will kick of the generateData function on the thread (since you moved the class to that thread). The timer will keep pulsing at 25 Hz, since it is actually a system call (and not an active wait on that thread). On Windows it might not be accurate enough.

Note that you cannot call moveToThread on this if it has parents, see [QT docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#moveToThread)
Also note that Class should be derived from QObject, but I think this is already the case since you are `connect`ing

Comment: The `QTimer` can be simply a child of the class, then moving the class will move the timer too (it moves all children). It is almost always incorrect for a thread to be moved to itself, and that's what you do when the thread is the child of the class. Something else should own both.

Comment: Currently the thread is not a member, but you are right, this solution can have some tweaks!